# Splitting <li> into two groups, left and right

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to split `li` into two groups, left and right, and their text alignment to left and right too.

The html file:

```
    <div class="lavalamp_left dark">
        <ul>
            <li class="logo" >HP WebStats</li>
            <li class="active"><a href="">Views</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Help</a></li>
            <li><a href="">About</a></li>
        </ul>
        <div class="floatr"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="lavalamp_right dark">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="">Edit</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Notes</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Logout</a></li>
        </ul>
        <div class="floatr"></div>
    </div>
```

This is the css file:

```
.lavalamp_left
{
    position: relative;
    border: 1px solid #d6d6d6;
    background: #fff;
    padding: 15px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 3px 6px rgba(0,0,0,.25);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 3px 6px rgba(0,0,0,.25);
    border-radius : 10px;
    -moz-border-radius : 10px;
    -webkit-border-radius : 10px;
    background : -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(rgb(240,240,240)), to(rgb(204,204,204)));
    background : -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgb(240,240,240), rgb(204,204,204));
    height: 18px;
    width: 63%;
    text-alight: left;
}

.lavalamp_right
{
    position: relative;
    border: 1px solid #d6d6d6;
    background: #fff;
    padding: 15px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 3px 6px rgba(0,0,0,.25);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 3px 6px rgba(0,0,0,.25);
    border-radius : 10px;
    -moz-border-radius : 10px;
    -webkit-border-radius : 10px;
    background : -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(rgb(240,240,240)), to(rgb(204,204,204)));
    background : -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgb(240,240,240), rgb(204,204,204));
    height: 18px;
    width: 33%;
    float: right;
    text-align: right;
}
```

The screenshot:

[image]

Even though the margins are set to 66% and 33%, the two bars does not want to be on the same "height". Also text-align does not make "edit", "notes", "logout" appear right to left.

Also I'm wondering if it's possible for a single  to place those links two seperate links right and left? Then I would not have to make two .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add `float:left` to `.lavalamp_left`  class

```
.lavalamp_left
{
    position: relative;
    border-radius : 10px;
    -moz-border-radius : 10px;
    -webkit-border-radius : 10px;
    background: #fff;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 3px 6px rgba(0,0,0,.25);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 3px 6px rgba(0,0,0,.25);
    background : -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(rgb(240,240,240)), to(rgb(204,204,204)));
    background : -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgb(240,240,240), rgb(204,204,204));
    height: 18px;
    width: 70%;
    text-align: left;
    float:left;
}

.lavalamp_right
{
    position: relative;
    background: #fff;
    border-radius : 10px;
    -moz-border-radius : 10px;
    -webkit-border-radius : 10px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 3px 6px rgba(0,0,0,.25);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 3px 6px rgba(0,0,0,.25);
    background : -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(rgb(240,240,240)), to(rgb(204,204,204)));
    background : -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgb(240,240,240), rgb(204,204,204));
    height: 18px;
    width: 30%;
    float: right;
    text-align: right;
}
```

you have set borders and padding to your left and right div . you must considering these properties value in final width of the page too.

I think is better to use padding for `ul` or `li` class directly and dont use in `lavalamp_left` or `lavalamp_right` class

Comment: Thanks for the help! Even though width is set to "share" the spaces between to <ul>. If you make the screen smaller, one would stack on each other. Why does this occur?

Comment: you have set borders and padding to your left and right div . you must considering these properties too. this [jsfiddle demo link](http://jsfiddle.net/v7rzofLv/3/) is fully responsive without border and padding

Answer (score 2):

By definition, [a div (division)](http://htmldog.com/guides/html/intermediate/spandiv/) element is block-line (which is basically equivalent to having a line-break before and after it) and used to group larger chunks of code. This is what is causing your headers to be on two different lines.

You could use a table instead of divs, like this:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td class="lavalamp_left dark">
                <ul>
                    <li class="logo">HP WebStats</li>
                    <li class="active"><a href="">Views</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="">Help</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="">About</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <div class="floatr"></div>
        </td>
        <td class="lavalamp_right dark">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="">Edit</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="">Notes</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="">Logout</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <div class="floatr"></div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

If you do this, however, the CSS would need a little more cleanup to get the effect you are going for.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to do it. Not really sure what you want but this is the easiest:

http://codepen.io/rema/pen/iozbK

Add simply `float: left` to `.lavalamp_left`

Here is another simple example:

http://codepen.io/rema/pen/Coevz

Answer (score 0):

Try putting those two  elements inside another container  and then the alignment should work.